# Remote Desktop Access using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, remote-access

In my project I am thinking of adding a technical support where a user will enter his/her queries .and my tech support will access the computer remotely and help to solve the problem. Its a web application and I am using laravel( php framework). I only have a little idea on how to do it. I have tried searching it . but it didn't gave me any proper result.

According to me it can be done by using Socket programming in which I have to get user's  Public Ip and his/her MAC address .because public ip can be same if two or pc are connected to same router(I think so).

I need some guidance on how to accomplish it. I have heard that laravel has a package for socket programming named as socket.io.

Please give me a proper path to walk on. I need guidance on what I will be needed in doing this. please help me.

Comment: http://socket.io/ has nothing to do with laravel. It's a stand alone project. They can work together but one is not the package of the other. If you want to control a PC remotely via php it will be unreasonable and stupidly hard. You cannot do such thing as Team Viewer with php alone, and if you want to control something you should have file to allow your access to the PC. Yes sockets are a MUST in this project because they are the tunnel to the other PC. If you want to control  somenone's pc try reading the code of some php shells. They have similar functionality via terminals in them.

Comment: Can u explain a bit more. My application is almost complete . and I have to implement this feature to. If possible tell me what to do to access the pc remotely. if php alone cant do the work than tell me what to do. any how i need this in my project.

Comment: Well I cannot explain you the whole logic behind it simply because its huge. Download one of the many shell scripts in the web ( they are all open and don't mind if some antivirus programs detect them as virus. If you are afraid you can always open them i VM ). So when you download one of it you will see how everything works. It's basically a file which if located on the server or in your case your user computer  can list directories CRUD files and such. There is even console in some of the shells so you can remotely install programs - from there you can get Team Veiwer and help your users.