# Remote PC access using two web browser with out installing any new application in OS

Tags: laravel, firemonkey, remote-access, remote-server

I have just got a web project where client wants to make an expert and client system. If client is having a problem in his PC he come to the forum and ask the expert to fix it .

All i want to know that how client's browser access his own PC, Send to expert and how expert will handle it.

I'm working in php Laravel but I'm stuck here badly.

Comment: show the code..

Comment: i have not yet coded any thing just searching for some thing from where to start but beleive me i can not find any thing help ful
"chrome remote desktop " work same as i want but that can not be integrated with any web site

Comment: I would recommend you going through [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6) basics of laravel.

Comment: also check comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38735473/remote-desktop-access-using-laravel)

Answer (score -1):

I do not think this is possible. The only thing that came up in my head is the Chrome Remote Desktop plugin.

You are also looking at the wrong languages. Laravel has nothing to do with this issue, because Laravel is a server-side language.

Comment: When downvoting I do want to know which part if this answer is wrong. It is a vague question and I don't know exactly how I can solve this issue for Babar. Any help would be appreciated.